# I'm wondering how to turn this city in java made of asterisks 90 degrees (so it actually looks like a city)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, printing

```
public class HelloWorld
{

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
       int[] arr = {5,10,23,6,9};
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {

            for( int j = 0; j< arr[i]; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");

            } 

            System.out.println();
        }
     }
}
```

That is my code, however, it prints the city horizontally, while I'd like it to print vertically. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building the city from top to bottom (that's how the printing works), you can keep track of the current height and put an asterisk if there should be one at that height and otherwise a space, for every column.

```
int[] arr = {5,10,23,6,9};
int max = 23; //you should do this dynamically in the general case
while(max > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] >= max) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    max--;
}
```

[Here](https://rextester.com/MMJE99071) is a working example.